# How to access a cell in a closed, external worksheet using a defined cell name rather than row and column

Tags: excel, vba

I have assigned:

- In "Worksheet_1" of "Workbook_1"
- the name "Cell_1" to cell "C1".

Using VBA in **Workbook_1 itself**, the value in C1 can be read using **Range("Cell_1").value**.

However:

- I wish to **access** "C1"
- from an **EXTERNAL** workbook
- **WITHOUT opening Workbook_1**
- referencing the cell via its **name** "Cell_1" rather than its **Row-Column coordinates** "C1".

I could envisage a function call such as:

- `ExecuteExcel4Macro = 'Path_1\[Workbook_1]Worksheet_1'!Range(**"Cell_1"**).Range(**"Cell_1"**).Range(**"Cell_1"**).Address(, , xlR1C1)`

but this obviously doesn't work since ExecuteExcel4Macro requires a row and a column.

Any suggestions as to how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way to go would be: Open the file (eg in background) read the value and close the file. You can do that in a way the user doesn't see that a file got opened. There are several tutorials on how to do that, give it a try. • I would't rely on an ancient technique like an `ExecuteExcel4Macro` macro anyway. This is only supported for compatibility reasons of old versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecuteExcel4Macro` syntax depends on the scope of the `Name`:

`Name` defined at `workbook` level:    `'Path\WbkName'!sName`
`Name` defined at `worksheet` level:   `'Path\[WbkName]WshName'!sName`

Try this functions:

```
Function WbkName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk(sPath As String, sWbkName As String, sName As String)
Dim sFml As String
    sFml = "'" & sPath & "\" & sWbkName & "'!" & sName
    WbkName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(sFml)
End Function
```

…

```
Function WshName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk(sPath As String, sWbkName As String, sWshName As String, sName As String)
Rem "'C:\@SOs\@SO Questions\[SOQ 66316733.xlsb]Sht1'!Cell_1
Dim sFml As String
    sFml = "'" & sPath & "\[" & sWbkName & "]" & sWshName & "'!" & sName
    WshName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(sFml)
End Function
```

The functions could be called like this:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim CllA As Range, CllB As Range
Dim sPath As String, sWbkName As String, sWshName As String, sName As String

    sPath = "C:\@SOs\@SO Questions"
    sWbkName = "SOQ 66316733.xlsb"
    sWshName = "Sht1"
    sName = "Cell_1"
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set CllA = .Cells(2, 2)
        Set CllB = .Cells(3, 2)
    End With
    
    CllA = WbkName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk(sPath, sWbkName, sName)
    CllB = WshName_ƒFrom_ClosedWbk(sPath, sWbkName, sWshName, sName)

End Sub
```

***Note:** The `ExecuteExcel4Macro` errors out when used in a `UDF` and returns `#VALUE!`*